# How to stop a jenkins job midway?

Tags: jenkins

I clicked on execute shell 3 times and have 3 shell scripts that jenkins runs during a build. How do I end a job mid build in one of the scripts?

I tried `exit` but that only ends the particular script and not the job.

Comment: What's the point of running 3 _Execute shell_ build steps in a row rather than putting all the code in one? Such ending the job when this one script ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the <kbd>(?)</kbd> help icon next to the "Execute Shell" field in your job configuration, you'll see that it says:

> the build is considered a failure if any of the commands exits with a non-zero exit code.

Therefore, if you detect that you want to stop the build from a shell script, you can use `exit 1` (to signify failure) rather than just calling `exit`, which is equivalent to `exit 0` (which signifies success).

This will stop the build immediately, marking it as a failure — no other build steps will be executed.